# Is it possible to make the compiler warnings reporting consistent between different versions of MS build engine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, roslyn, compiler-warnings

I have a C# project targeting .NET Core 3.1 where I resolved all compiler warnings and set `TreatWarningsAsErrors` to `true`. It builds just fine both from Visual Studio and the command line.

However, the build on the build server fails and reports one of the warnings as an error: CS8625. The only difference I can spot is the version of the MS build engine:

- **16.8.3** locally
- **16.7.2** on a build server

I failed to find the explicit information in the release notes, but it's my gut feeling that the changes between the mentioned versions are the root cause of such behavior.

Obviously, I can disable the mentioned warning in the `.editorconfig` file, and it won't be reported both locally and on a build server, but I would prefer it to behave the other way around.

Is it possible to set things up the way the warnings are reported consistently disregarding the build engine version?

Comment: Consistent with what? The only way I imagine that could work would be a flag to force a newer version to use the same warning rules as an older version. But then you would miss out of any improvements to the warnings. It seem like an easier fix would be to just use the same version everywhere. Also, I would expect it to be the c# compiler, csc.exe, that generates warnings, not MSBuild, but they are probably part of the same installation.

Comment: Can you show one or two code examples of that warning and the complete message?

Comment: It could also be a version of Roslyn, not related to MSBuild. Both MSBuild and Roslyn evolve rapidly, so it's hard to expect that their behavior will be identical across all versions. You can temporarily fix or ignore the warning so that your CI passes until it gets updated to a newer MSBuild. See here for an example: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39906

Comment: @KirillOsenkov Thanks, that's what I ended up doing after discussing with my team members. Could you please shape your comment into an answer as it quite a viable approach and might help others facing similar issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could also be a version of Roslyn, not related to MSBuild. Both MSBuild and Roslyn evolve rapidly, so it's hard to expect that their behavior will be identical across all versions. You can temporarily fix or ignore the warning so that your CI passes until it gets updated to a newer MSBuild.

See here for an example: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39906